# Difference in behavior of Python versions when no virtual environment is found

Tags: python, uwsgi, python-venv, python-3.9, backtrace

I would like to know if there any behavior changes in Python since version 3.6 that are relevant to my issue.

I am using uWSGI containers to run Django applications. I recently decided to upgrade my containers to use Python 3.9, but ran into an issue that doesn’t seem to be uWSGI version dependent.

With Python 3.6 if uWSGI master process doesn’t find virtual environment directory, this causes a segmentation fault, the process exits with code 1 and can then restart with the fallback configuration.

With Python 3.9 uWSGI master process exits without a segmentation fault, so it doesn’t use the fallback configuration.

**uWSGI 2.0.18 / Python version: 3.6.8**

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Sat Mar 11 21:33:34 2023] ***
compiled with version: 8.3.1 20190507 (Red Hat 8.3.1-4) on 27 January 2020 10:45:00
os: Linux-6.1.14-200.fc37.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun Feb 26 00:13:26 UTC 2023
nodename: 22c3284023fa
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /var/www
writing pidfile to /run/uwsgi/uwsgi.pid
detected binary path: /usr/sbin/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 30960
limiting address space of processes...
your process address space limit is 268435456 bytes (256 MB)
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
 *** WARNING: you have enabled harakiri without post buffering. Slow upload could be rejected on post-unbuffered webservers *** 
detected max file descriptor number: 524288
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
[busyness] settings: min=20%, max=70%, overload=1, multiplier=30, respawn penalty=2
[busyness] backlog alert is set to 16 request(s), step is 2
[busyness] backlog non-zero alert is set to 60 second(s)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:9000 fd 3
Python version: 3.6.8 (default, Jan 25 2023, 15:03:30)  [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18)]
!!! Python Home is not a directory: env !!!
Set PythonHome to env
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f1a5cefb600 (most recent call first):
!!! uWSGI process 1 got Segmentation Fault !!!
*** backtrace of 1 ***
/usr/sbin/uwsgi(uwsgi_backtrace+0x2e) [0x46a37e]
/usr/sbin/uwsgi(uwsgi_segfault+0x27) [0x46a767]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x4eb50) [0x7f1a5a7e6b50]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x203) [0x7f1a5a7b9f81]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(Py_FatalError+0x17c) [0x7f1a59c76bb7]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x9d5bc) [0x7f1a59cab5bc]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_Py_InitializeEx_Private+0x21b) [0x7f1a59e1b0fb]
/usr/lib64/uwsgi/python3_plugin.so(uwsgi_python_init+0x142) [0x7f1a5a3650b2]
/usr/sbin/uwsgi(uwsgi_start+0x5a7) [0x46b9d7]
/usr/sbin/uwsgi(uwsgi_setup+0x1317) [0x46dd27]
/usr/sbin/uwsgi(main+0xf) [0x418f7f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe5) [0x7f1a5a7d2d85]
/usr/sbin/uwsgi(_start+0x2e) [0x418fbe]
*** end of backtrace ***
VACUUM: pidfile removed.
Sat Mar 11 21:33:34 2023 - !!! /usr/sbin/uwsgi (pid: 1) exited with status 1 !!!
Sat Mar 11 21:33:34 2023 - !!! Fallback config to /etc/uwsgi.d/safe.ini !!!
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi.d/safe.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Sat Mar 11 21:33:34 2023] ***
compiled with version: 8.3.1 20190507 (Red Hat 8.3.1-4) on 27 January 2020 10:45:00
os: Linux-6.1.14-200.fc37.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun Feb 26 00:13:26 UTC 2023
nodename: 22c3284023fa
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /var/www
detected binary path: /usr/sbin/uwsgi
chdir() to /var/www
your processes number limit is 30960
limiting address space of processes...
your process address space limit is 268435456 bytes (256 MB)
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
 *** WARNING: you have enabled harakiri without post buffering. Slow upload could be rejected on post-unbuffered webservers *** 
detected max file descriptor number: 524288
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 inherited INET address 127.0.0.1:9000 fd 3
Python version: 3.6.8 (default, Jan 25 2023, 15:03:30)  [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18)]
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1fba2b0
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 218760 bytes (213 KB) for 2 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x1fba2b0 pid: 1 (default app)
gracefully (RE)spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 2, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 3, cores: 1)
*** Stats server enabled on 127.0.0.1:9999 fd: 11 ***
```

**uWSGI 2.0.18 / Python version: 3.9.16**

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Mon Mar 13 09:22:18 2023] ***
compiled with version: 11.2.1 20210728 (Red Hat 11.2.1-2) on 27 January 2021 00:00:00
os: Linux-6.1.14-200.fc37.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun Feb 26 00:13:26 UTC 2023
nodename: 8c5999467f48
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /var/www
writing pidfile to /run/uwsgi/uwsgi.pid
detected binary path: /usr/sbin/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 30960
limiting address space of processes...
your process address space limit is 268435456 bytes (256 MB)
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
 *** WARNING: you have enabled harakiri without post buffering. Slow upload could be rejected on post-unbuffered webservers *** 
detected max file descriptor number: 524288
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
[busyness] settings: min=20%, max=70%, overload=1, multiplier=30, respawn penalty=2
[busyness] backlog alert is set to 16 request(s), step is 2
[busyness] backlog non-zero alert is set to 60 second(s)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:9000 fd 3
Python version: 3.9.16 (main, Dec  8 2022, 00:00:00)  [GCC 11.3.1 20221121 (Red Hat 11.3.1-4)]
!!! Python Home is not a directory: env !!!
Set PythonHome to env
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'env'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'env/bin/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/var/www/env/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = 'env'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'env'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib64'
  sys.executable = '/var/www/env/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = 'env'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'env'
  sys.path = [
    'env/lib64/python39.zip',
    'env/lib64/python3.9',
    'env/lib64/python3.9/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f8817848780 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
VACUUM: pidfile removed.
```

**uWSGI 2.0.21 / Python version: 3.9.16**

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.21 (64bit) on [Sat Mar 11 21:11:36 2023] ***
compiled with version: 11.2.1 20220127 (Red Hat 11.2.1-9) on 28 October 2022 00:00:00
os: Linux-6.1.14-200.fc37.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun Feb 26 00:13:26 UTC 2023
nodename: f6e77e6845c9
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /var/www
writing pidfile to /run/uwsgi/uwsgi.pid
detected binary path: /usr/sbin/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 30960
limiting address space of processes...
your process address space limit is 268435456 bytes (256 MB)
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
 *** WARNING: you have enabled harakiri without post buffering. Slow upload could be rejected on post-unbuffered webservers *** 
detected max file descriptor number: 524288
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
[busyness] settings: min=20%, max=70%, overload=1, multiplier=30, respawn penalty=2
[busyness] backlog alert is set to 16 request(s), step is 2
[busyness] backlog non-zero alert is set to 60 second(s)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:9000 fd 3
Python version: 3.9.16 (main, Dec  8 2022, 00:00:00)  [GCC 11.3.1 20221121 (Red Hat 11.3.1-4)]
!!! Python Home is not a directory: env !!!
Set PythonHome to env
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'env'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'env/bin/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/var/www/env/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = 'env'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'env'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib64'
  sys.executable = '/var/www/env/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = 'env'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'env'
  sys.path = [
    'env/lib64/python39.zip',
    'env/lib64/python3.9',
    'env/lib64/python3.9/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f0703dcc780 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
VACUUM: pidfile removed.
```

It seems strange to me that with Python 3.9 I get `<no Python frame>` message instead of a backtrace. I tried searching the web for more details, but didn’t find anything informative.

Please, explain to me what’s going on and how can I get back the desired behavior.